# How can I make the npm start IP address sync with php artisan serve to use backend functionality on mobile device?

Tags: php, reactjs, laravel, debugging

I have a React.js frontend project and Laravel backend project separated.  I can access my frontend project via the local host address provided upon running `npm start` so I can see the frontend on a physical device of what I'm working on.

However - When I try to login (backend functionality) on my physical device, it won't allow me to.  `php artisan serve`'s running on my backend project and I can successfully login on the browser without any issues so my login system isn't the issue.

I guess my question is - how can I make it so that my physical device knows that `php artisan serve`'s running so I can access my web app with the localhost address given to me provided by `npm start`?

In other words - how can I make `127.0.0.1:8000` (`php artisan serve`) sync up with `192.168.2.165:3000` (`npm start`)?

Comment: `php artisan serve --host=192.168.2.165 --port=3000`

Comment: @DilipHirapara I've tried that already but on my mobile device it's showing the Laravel project and not the React project

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to have your app request proxied to your backend server. take a look at this from Create-react-app doc : https://create-react-app.dev/docs/proxying-api-requests-in-development/

Based on your description you should add this line to your package.json for your react app :

```
"proxy": "http://192.168.2.165:8000"
```